# Convert one-many to one-one with insert and update MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a script which will modify a relationship from one-many to one-one. The one-many relationship is a phone number with a primary key that could be referenced by different tables multiple times.

For example, let's say I have a table for undergraduates and one for graduates and two entries have the same number. Right now they will have the same foreign key for the phone number table.

I would like to insert a new row into the phone number table (with the same data) for whenever these students are using the same foreign key id, and update one of the student rows to point to the newly inserted phone number row.

I have insert and update statements shown below, and I basically need to find a way to combine the two.

```
INSERT INTO phone_number (id, phone_number)
SELECT null, pn.number
FROM phone_number pn
    WHERE pn.id in 
    (
        SELECT underp.phone_id
        FROM 
        (
        undergraduate_phone underp
            INNER JOIN graduate_phone gradp ON underp.phone_id = gradp.phone_id
    )
        )

UPDATE graduate_phone
    SET graduate_phone.phone_id = LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

What I have now obviously won't work because the insert statement just copies all of the rows in phone_number that are used by both undergrad and grads and the update statement only gets the last inserted id. Thoughts?

Comment: Look into using a `TRIGGER`. This will run for each row you insert, thus avoiding your current issue.

Comment: Would using a trigger make sense if I only need to make this conversion to one-one once? Looks useful